# passing the type parameter dynamically to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, oop

```
public class Access
{
    public Entity eeee { get; set; }
    public Permission<eeee.GetType()> pppp { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{

}

public class Permission<T>
{
    public bool CanView {get;set;}
    public bool CanEdit {get;set;}
    public bool CanDelete {get;set;}

}

public class Photo:Entity
{
}

public class PhotoPermission:Permission<Photo>
{
    public bool CanTag {get;set;}
}

public class Video:Entity
{

}

public class VideoPermission:Permission<Video>
{
    public bool CanFastForward {get;set;}
}
```

So, If `eeee` is of type `Photo`, then the "type" of `pppp` should be `Permission<Photo>`

Is there something like `eeee.GetType()`

Comment: Why can't you just change `public Permission<eeee.GetType()> pppp { get; set; }` to `public Permission<Entity> pppp { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can very easily change your `Access` class to

```
public class Access<T>
{
    public T eeee { get; set; }
    public Permission<T> pppp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind generics is that the generic type is known at runtime; therefore, your code would not compile. I suggest you to use Reflection to accomplish your task.